# Помогите сделать метод и его вызвать

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, я новичок в java, не могли бы вы мне помочь 
можно ли из этого кода сделать метод и потом вызывать его, а так он очень уж громоздкий, и как это сделать? Тут я создаю диалог со списком и обрабатываю нажатие на элемент диалога.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id){
        case KEY:
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Stop1.this);
            b.setTitle("Пересадка");
            b.setPositiveButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            b.setItems(city, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
                    switch(position) {
                        case 0:
                            startActivity(new Intent(Stop1.this, number_11.class));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
                return b.create();
            default:
                return  null;
    }
}
```

Comment: это и ест метод, а вызвать его можно создав объект каласса в котором он находится, например `Clazz obj = new Clazz(); obj.method(param...);`

Comment: и да что бы уменьшит код нужно использовать лямбды, + разбить на несколько методов(на обработчик один метод который будет создаваться в данном классе), имя такого метода любое, главное что бы параметры совпадали, могу написать пример

Comment: Ещё бы знать что это такое, может у вас есть ссылка на теорию желательно на русском.?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/

Comment: ах да protected меняем на public, метод вы сскорец всего не в своем пакете вызываете

Comment: в каком смысле?

Comment: Напишите пример кода плиз как оно должно выглядеть я просто чайник полный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Рекомендуемая литература:* Роберт Мартин. Чистый код: создание, анализ и рефакторинг. Библиотека программиста. - СПб.: Питер, 2010. - 464 с.: ил.

Как вам правильно уже указали в комментарии - ваш код уже является методом, который можно вызвать, его нужно *отрефакторить*.

Например, это может выглядеть так (простите за возможные неточности по синтаксису, мой "родной" язык C#):

1 Возможно нужно вообще избавиться от корневого `switch` и заменить его на `if`, но так как я вижу, что там используется именованная константа, пока воздержусь от такого рефакторинга, т. к. возможно в дальнейшем будут добавлены еще ветки.

2 Избавляемся от вложенности (хорошие имена для методов вы должны будете придумать самостоятельно, т. к. мне неизвестен весь контекст):

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id){
        case KEY:
            return createKeyDialog();
        default:
            return  null;
    }
}

private Dialog createKeyDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Stop1.this);
    b.setTitle("Пересадка");
    b.setPositiveButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    b.setItems(city, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    startActivity(new Intent(Stop1.this, number_11.class));
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    return b.create();
}
```

3 Избавляемся от вложенности:

```
private Dialog createKeyDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Stop1.this);
    b.setTitle("Пересадка");
    b.setPositiveButton("Отмена", createPositiveListener());
    b.setItems(city, createItemsListener());
    return b.create();
}

private ... createPositiveListener() {
    return new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}

private ... createItemsListener() {
    return new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
            switch(position) {
                case 0:
                    startActivity(new Intent(Stop1.this, number_11.class));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И так далее.

4 Избавляемся от магических констант:
Здесь нужно как-то именовать такие константы, как: `"Пересадка"`, `"Отмена"` - это позволит в дальнейшем их отредактировать в одном месте, а также при возможной локализации на другие языки.

5 Улучшаем читаемость имен:
Бросается в глаза непонятное `Stop1`, также рекомендую привести к единому стилю (camelCase) имя: `number_11`